# White bar at the bottom to the view

Tags: ios

I have a background image on a view controller, it is shown as expected on the simulator,  but on a real device, a white bar is shown at the bottom of the screen. On another view, with another background image, the white bar appears on the top of the screen. Any hint to detect the source of the issue? It doesn't happened on the simulator, it happens only on a real device, it is an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.

Comment: I assume you are simulating with an iPhone 4 also, did you check the restrictions? The width/height/etc? Are you working with the generic dimensions or just for iPhone 4 in our storyboard?

Comment: @CrisR, I am working with Xcode 6 and using Autolayout and Image Assets.

Comment: can you share some screenshots showing your Storyboard, the simulator, and the real device?

Comment: @CrisR, I have change the code and add the background image programmatically. Now it works fine. Thank you.